# When I run the Windows11Installer, it is immediately closed

Tags: windows

I installed Windows 11 preview beta in August 2021.
Now, I want to switch to stable Windows 11 without format.

- First, I stopped the insider program.
- And I downloaded Windows11Installer.
  But when I run the Installer, it
  is immediately closed.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have to back up your data and install Windows 11 as a fresh install.

That is normal with Windows Insider Preview versions. That is clear in the Windows Insider agreements.

Also beware that Windows 11 Preview will run on machines that do not support Windows 11 Production.

Comment: Maybe I back up my data, but the installed apps must be removed, and maybe I can not install some of them again. Is there any method for backing up them also?

Comment: You need the app installers to reinstall the apps. Some apps may not be compliant and thus require upgrading or different apps. I had a couple of apps that were uninstalled with later versions of Windows 10 Insider and then Windows 11 Preview.